# Making my "title" text show up on the navbar

Tags: html, css, web

I am currently making my first mockup website, fiddled around with making a navbar and having a logo on it. I've managed to do it, but now when I try to add the 'name' onto the navbar it won't show up.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
}


/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation-bar img {
  float: left;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.navigation-bar li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.navigation-bar title {
  color: red;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <title>The Fox Den</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- logo -->
  <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">

  <!-- buttons -->
  <div class="navigation-bar">
    <div id=navigation-container>
      <h1 class="title">The<span>Coffee</span>shop</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- end of buttons -->

</body>

</html>
```

I've tried moving the text around to different places, but it ends up moving the navbar to be under the text.

Comment: Change the `color: whitesmoke` into something visible

Comment: It appears visible when on the nav-bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `.navigation-bar ul` to be `float: right`. `float` removes items from the normal flow of the page, which is why it is leaving your navbar.

You can fix this using `flexbox`, by adding the following rules to `.navigation-bar ul`:

```
.navigation-bar ul{
  ...
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

---

Here are some extra observations on your code, that are unrelated to the main problem

There are several places where you have hardcoded the height of the navbar - this could instead be replaced with a CSS variable - i.e.

```
:root{
  --navbar-height: 70px;
}

.logo {
  height: calc(var(--navbar-height) - 10px);
}

#navigation-container {
  height: var(--navbar-height);
}

.navigation-bar {
  height: var(--navbar-height);
}

/* etc */
```

You should try to avoid pixel units where possible as these are not responsive -  instead, the preferred unit is `rem`s.

However, in this case I don't actually think you need to set the height - the content inside (i.e. the header, logo and navbar) should instead make the header resize. This is particularly important for responsive pages.

Adapted code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
}


/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation-bar img {
  float: left;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.navigation-bar li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.navigation-bar title {
  color: red;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <title>The Fox Den</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- logo -->
  <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">

  <!-- buttons -->
  <div class="navigation-bar">
    <div id=navigation-container>
      <h1 class="title">The<span>Coffee</span>shop</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- end of buttons -->

</body>

</html>
```